# NSCache, image release, async queue

Tags: ios, interface, nsstring, selector

This is supposed to display a placeholder in my any given table row unless an image for that indexpath exists. When I scroll down, the images from the previous indexPath loads over the default instead of releasing. I know someone helped me with the same problem before, but this was before I realized the importance of caching the images.  In my customCell method I have UIImage property set to strong, and I release the images for viewDidUnload.

```
NSString *imagename = [_imageCache objectForKey:indexPath];
UIImage *preview = [_imageCache objectForKey:imagename];

if (preview)
{
    [[cell myImageView] setImage:preview];
}
else
{
    [[cell myImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellLogo.png"]];

            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

             //   __block UIImage *preview = nil;               
               UIImage *preview = [UIImage imageWithData:object.iG];
              //             }
         if (preview)
         {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 //   if (cell)
                    [[cell myImageView] setImage:preview];

                });
             [_imageCache setObject:preview forKey:imagename];
         }
            });
}
```

Comment: Where's your imageFileName function? Are you thinking that's a system function?...cuzzzzz....no its not

Comment: Looks like you have completely changed the question to a new one. What happened to the old one?

Comment: I did a bad thing :(... As soon as I posted the question I figured I'd try something, and it worked. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you haven't declared `imageFilename:` anywhere in your code. There are no such methods by default and if you wish you can define a method in that name in current class as:

```
- (NSString *)imageFilename:(NSIndexpath *)indexpath {
  //code here
}
```

If you have already used it somewhere else, you need to import that particular class and call this method as `NSString *imagename = [myobject imageFilename:indexPath];` where `myobject` is the object of that class.

Comment: The above answer is applicable only to the question which was there before. Looks like it is modified to a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "cell reuse".  You need to implement -prepareForReuse in your UITableViewCell subclass.  It should reset the image to a placeholder or blank image.